# Need to be able to display a clickable href button (to allow user to progress to next page) if a user achieves a specified score in a quiz

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

So I am creating a quiz on social engineering each with 5 different pages. Each page has a quiz. I want the user to be able to proceed to the next page of the website, if they get a score of >= 75. The quiz is out of 100 and there are 5 questions. Each correct answer is worth 25. Meaning 5/5 = 100 etc.

In addition to this, when the user clicks submit now, the page refreshes, how can I stop this? as sometimes the user clicks submit and the page just calculates the score only, but sometimes the page calculates the score and refreshes the page which I do not want.

Any help is **MASSIVELY** appreciated. ***TIA***

Please see below for the code I am currently using :)

```
<form id="form1">

<p6> <strong> Question 1: True or False, the following image below shows an example of a phishing attempt.</strong> </p6>
<br>
 <div class="bestbuy-example"></div>

<label for="bestbuy"> <input type="radio" name="bestbuy" value="20" id="bestbuy"/>True</label> <br>
<label for="bestbuy"> <input type="radio" name="bestbuy" value="0" id="bestbuy"/>False</label> <br>

<br> <p6> <strong> Question 2: What is the best way an organization can prevent phishing attacks?</strong> </p6> </br>

<label for="prevent"> <input type="radio" name="prevent" value="0" id="prevent"/>Educate staff and provide training</label> <br>
<label for="prevent"><input type="radio" name="prevent" value="0" id="prevent" />Install Anti-Virus on all company equipment</label> <br>
<label for="prevent"> <input type="radio" name="prevent" value="0" id="prevent"/>Ensure systems are all up to date and software security is checked</label> <br>
<label for="prevent"> <input type="radio" name="prevent" value="0" id="prevent"/>Use web filters that block malicious websites</label> <br>
<label for="prevent"> <input type="radio" name = "prevent" value="20" id="prevent"/>All of the above </label><br>

<br><p6><strong>Question 3: You receive an email from <strong> hmrc.fines@gmail.com </strong> It states that you have you are eligible for a tax refund (rebate) of 178.91 GBP due to coronavirus reasons. There is hyperlink that says, ‘access your funds now’. What should you do? </strong> </p6> </br>

<label for="hmrc"> <input type="radio" name="hmrc" value="0" id="hmrc"/>Click the link and claim your tax refund </label> <br>
<label for="hmrc"> <input type="radio" name="hmrc" value="20" id="hmrc" />Report the email using the link: 'https://www.gov.uk/report-suspicious-emails-websites-phishing/report-hmrc-phishing-emails-texts-and-phone-call-scams'</label> <br>
<label for="hmrc"> <input type="radio" name="hmrc" value="0"  id="hmrc"/>Move the email to your junk folder </label> <br>
<label for="hmrc"> <input type="radio" name="hmrc" value="0" id="hmrc"/>Forward the email to friends and family to also claim their rebate</label> </br>

<br> <p6><strong>Question 4: You have just realised that you have fallen for a phishing scam. What should you do?:</strong></p6> </br>

<label for="email"> <input type="radio" name="email" value="0" id="email"/>Delete the phishing email from your inbox</label> <br>
<label for="email"> <input type="radio" name="email" value="0" id="email"/>Turn off your computer to delete the virus</label> <br>
<label for="email"> <input type="radio" name="email" value="20"  id="email"/>Change any compromised passwords</label> </br>

<br> <p6><strong>Question 5: You receive a PayPal email telling you that your account has been suspended. It tells you that somebody has breached your account so you must login to update your password. Which of the following senders would mean that the email sent is legitimate?</strong></p6> </br>

<label for="paypal"> <input type="radio" name="paypal" value="20" id="paypal"/>service@paypal.com</label> <br>
<label for="paypal"> <input type="radio" name="paypal" value="0" id="paypal"/>paypal.services@gmail.com</label> <br>
<label for="paypal"> <input type="radio" name="paypal" value="0" id="paypal"/>help.paypal@outlook.com </label><br>
<label for="paypal"> <input type="radio" name="paypal" value="0" id="paypal"/>paypalsupport.paypal@yahoo.com </label><br> </br>

<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>

</form id="form1">

<p>Your grade is: <span id="grade2">___</span></p> <!-- Shows User Grade !-->
<p id="grade2"></p>

<button onclick="Function()">Next section</button>
<script> function Function() {
 location.replace("Malware.html")
}

</script>
</body>
</html>

<script>

document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function(){

  bestbuy = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "bestbuy"]:checked').value);
  prevent = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "prevent"]:checked').value);
  hmrc = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "hmrc"]:checked').value);
  email = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "email"]:checked').value);
  paypal = parseInt(document.querySelector('input[name = "paypal"]:checked').value);

result = bestbuy + prevent + hmrc + email + paypal;

document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result

if (result ==  0) {result2 = "Not good enough, you could potentially become a victim of social engineering in the future"};
if (result ==  25) {result2 = "You need to spend more time reading the information provided. Try again"};
if (result ==  50) {result2 = "You could do better, try again"};
if (result == 75) {result2 = "Good job."};
if (result == 100) {result2 = "Perfect! You clearly understand the dangers of Phishing"};
document.getElementById("grade2").innerHTML = result2;

return false;
} //ends the submit function

</script>
  </body>
```

Comment: You have `</body></html>` and then another `</body>` at the end. Also I guess the word `Function` is a reserved keyword of the language, you can't call a function "Function". Also I guess you probably want `if (result <=  25)`, `if (result <=  50)` instead of strict equality `if (result ==  25)`

Comment: `</form id="form1">` is wrong... and `Function` is a keyword in JavaScipt... I don't know how your code is working as it is. Could you make a [mcve]?

Comment: How come </form id="form1" is wrong? I am fairly new to HTML so appreciate the help people :)

Comment: anyone know how I can add a a href link into one of the if statements referring to result2?

Comment: @renz900 when closing a tag you don't need to specify it's attributes. so `</form id="form1">` should be just `</form>` That being said, there are a LOT of problems ( as the others pointed out in the comments ) . Try to fix those first ( form closing tag, name of the Function -> change that ) and then edit your question